# ElasticSearch: Adding kerberos authentication using Jest Client

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

We have to implement kerberos authentication using Jest client in our application.

Maven dependency:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
>         <version>${jest.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

There is no proper example on their GitHub page for kerberos [authentication](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest#authentication).

Can someone guide me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

`jest` is not the official client of elasticsearch and elasticsearch now offers the official client called [JHLRC](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) which seems to support the `kerberos` auth.

You can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/kerberos-realm.html) and [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rest-client-any-other-authentication-mechanism/83790) related link for more info

Comment: We will have to stick with  JestClient only, the documentation mentions support for kerberos but misses how to configure it.

Comment: @SumanthHedge did you find a solution for this, I too was looking for kerb with keytab for Jest Client as the cluster is still at 5.6.2